Connected components of the space of max-rank $N\times n$ matrices
Consider the standard action of $SO_n$ on $N$-tuples of $n$-vectors. Let $M_N\subset (\mathbb{R}^n)^N$ be the open subset consisting of tuples that are "generic", i.e., linearly independent for $N\leq n$ and spanning all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $N>n$. The induced action on $M_N$ is proper and all orbits have conjugate stabilizers, so the orbit space $M_N/SO_n$ is smooth. How many connected components does it have? This is same as the number of connected components in the space of all maximum-rank matrices of size $N\times n$. I'm mostly interested in the case $N\geq n$.
What I'm familiar with is H. Weyl's theorem from his 1939 book stating that $M_N/O_n$ can be parametrized by functions of only the pairwise dot products of the vectors (this is an overcomplete basis), so this space is connected. The extra parity-sensitive invariants one gets on $M_N/SO_n$ are the signs of $n\times n$ determinants composed of any $n$ out of our $N$ vectors as columns. There are $2^{\binom{N}{n}}$ possible values, but this is obviously a huge overestimate.
For example, in the case $n=2$, one vector can always be pointed along the $x$-axis by an $SO_2$-action, and then the "angular order" of the remaining $N-1$ vectors determines a connected component, so there are $(N-1)!$ of them, which is asymptotically much less than $2^{\binom{N}{2}}$.

So $M_N$ is the preimage of the nonzero points of $\Lambda^N(R^n)$ under the natural morphism. Therefore, $N \leq n$, and $M_N$ is isomorphic to the set of matrices with rank $N$ in $M_{n \times N}(\mathbb{R})$ with the canonical $\mathrm{SO}_n$-action. Then I think the question can be simplied.

apologies, I actually meant to define $M_N$ as the set of "generic" tuples, see the edit. For $N\leq n$ that's the same as what you said, but I'm interested in all $N$, especially high $N$.

Ok, then $M_N$ is isomorphic to the set of matrices with rank $\max{ n, N}$.
